# Как хранить ключи react-native (expo)

Tags: react-native

У меня 3 релиз канала - dev, qa, prod.

```
const ENV_MODES = {
  dev: {

  },
  prod: {

  },
  qa: { 

  }
}

ENV_MODES.default = ENV_MODES.prod

const getEnvVars = channel => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') return ENV_MODES.dev
  if (channel === null || channel === undefined || channel === '') return ENV_MODES.prod
  if (channel.startsWith(ENV_DEV)) return ENV_MODES.dev
  if (channel.startsWith(ENV_QA)) return ENV_MODES.qa
  if (channel.startsWith(ENV_PROD)) return ENV_MODES.prod
  return ENV_MODES.default
}

const ENV = getEnvVars(Constants.manifest.releaseChannel)
```

Я не хочу хранить ключи в репозитории? Какие есть best practices?
Как я понимаю я не могу рассчитывать на NODE_ENV или не пойму как тут его правильно использовать. Ведь если я запаблишу на qa node_env у меня не будет qa